# Eloquent Controller - change db value with regex

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a MongoDB collection which has some values set to `false`. However, when I populate the table in my view these `false` values don't get printed.

I was thinking about changing their value before passing the variable to the view by going through all the elements and simply substitute `false` with a "-" sign (it's a pricing page).

Do you think this is the best approach to solve this problem? How would you do it? Do you have other suggestions to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is how a `false` value is being displayed, that's an issue for the "view" part of "model-view-controller" (MVC).

So, for example, in your blade template, you can do something like this:

```
{{ $model->value ? "it's true" : "it's false" }}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if I need to change only one element. However, I have a list of them, and I would like to go through all of them. For instance, I have the $plans variable which takes various plans from the db. These plans have a lot of fields within, can you show me an example to check all of them (through a foreach?) by accessing $plans[$i]->field?